# Postsharp - Get Calling Assembly?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

When using a Postsharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect, is there some way to get the calling assembly that initiated the call to a given method? GetCallingAssembly just returns the assembly that the method being called is in.

Note - I am having trouble with the postsharp forums, otherwise I would have posted it there.

Answer (score 0):

No; there is no way.

The only way is to walk the stack using System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.

Comment: But what is your problem with the PostSharp forum? Nobody complains any more, so i guess it's more or less stable...

Comment: Walking through the stack is not such a pain: http://geekswithblogs.net/alternativedotnet/archive/2006/02/04/68162.aspx, Check the GetCallingAssemblies() method impementation.